# How to return ordened array names?

Tags: python, sorting

I have an array I want to sort from low to high, but I want it to return the array names (G, F, H...) instead of just the numbers. How do I do this?

```
A=12.74087388       
B=12.48817861
C=12.31249807
D=12.95688859
E=12.49693343
F=11.51090636
G=10.16505019
H=11.99872655

Array=np.array([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H])
sort=np.sort(Array)
```

Comment: The identifier you assigned them to isn't a property of those values; see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: You will HAVE to make a dictionary or nested list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
d = dict(A=12.74087388,       
B=12.48817861,
C=12.31249807,
D=12.95688859,
E=12.49693343,
F=11.51090636,
G=10.16505019,
H=11.99872655)
```

and sort by value:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get)
['G', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D']
```

or keep the numbers and sort by value:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Output:

```
[('G', 10.16505019),
 ('F', 11.51090636),
 ('H', 11.99872655),
 ('C', 12.31249807),
 ('B', 12.48817861),
 ('E', 12.49693343),
 ('A', 12.74087388),
 ('D', 12.95688859)]
```

Comment: The problem is that this way I always have to type those long numbers. Is there a way to avoid this? (This is only a small part of all the numbers I want to sort)

Comment: Where do get these number from? From a file? Read the file into a dictionary right away.

Comment: It's from a netcdf file. Thanks I'll try that!

Answer (score 2):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, the variable name isn't a property of those values, so you'll have to attach it differently. I think the easiest way is to go about it like this:

```
my_array = [[12.74087388, 'A'], [12.48817861, 'B'], etc]
my_sorted_array = sorted(my_array)
my_sorted_named_array = [i[1] for i in my_sorted_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you prefer a list of tuples instead of a dictionary in case you have duplicated letters.

```
data = [
  ('A', 12.74087388),
  ('B', 12.48817861),
  ('C', 12.31249807),
  ('D', 12.95688859),
  ('E', 12.49693343),
  ('F', 11.51090636),
  ('G', 10.16505019),
  ('H', 11.99872655)
]
dt = np.dtype([('letter', np.unicode_, 1), ('num', np.float64)])
arr = np.array(data, dtype=dt)
arr.sort(order='num')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary-based solution, as suggested in the comments.

```
lst = [12.74087388, 12.48817861, 12.31249807, 12.95688859,
       12.49693343, 11.51090636, 10.16505019, 11.99872655]

d = dict(zip(list('ABCDEFGH'), lst))
sorted_names = list(zip(*sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))[0]

# ('G', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D')
```